# Evaluate differences between two files

Tags: diff

Is there a way in Unix, to evaluate how similar or dissimilar, two text files are?

I know about `diff`, but it just gives me the differences itself. What I am after is to just receive as an answer, some kind of evaluation of how much alike those two texts are. Do they contain much the same words, are the texts often quite similar etc. It is actually quite complicated to evaluate this in a high quality manner so I'm wondering if somebody has already done this.

Would be good to just receive a number, could then be that 0 means they are identical, and a high number means they are nothing alike.

Comment: There's an active research field related to this.  Depending on what you want to do, answers can range from n-grams to sentiment analysis, to opinion mining, to automatic corpora classification.

Comment: Do you know of any open source solutions? Would be a shame if I spent work on something thats already been done and open sourced somewhere else.

Comment: Your question is too broad to have an useful answer.

Comment: How could I narrow it down?

Answer (score 2):

There is `diffstat` which reads normal `diff` output and prints some stats more *about lines only*.

```
diff -u fileA fileB | diffstat
```

or `wdiff` to handle *word diffs*.

```
wdiff -123 --statistics fileA fileB
```

You may also read the man pages to find some more interesting options.